Is 2 hours enough from bus to plane in Tallinn?
I currently have a bus ticket that arrives at 11:40 at Tallinn Bus station, and I have a flight at 13:45 from Ulemiste. Is this a realistic schedule? I bought the bus tickets in a hurry as the buses were getting full already in March, but I am now worried. Perhaps the conference organizers will offer a bus at an earlier time, but it is not clear yet.

That's a stiff 20 minute walk, or a short tram ride.
If you're on some budget flight, you should be more than fine, though you wouldn't want to run up a delay with the arrival of your bus.

Here they write that the airport is not accessible by tram but I assume there is some replacement https://news.err.ee/1609078363/deputy-mayor-airport-inaccessible-by-tram-for-at-least-two-more-years I fly with Lufthansa.
